Spring Data Jpa @Procedure giving error for multiple out parametes
The below code is a stored procedure call with multiple out parameters. But when executed it is giving.
could not determine procedurecall parameter bind type - out (8)
@Procedure(name = "Pr_Get_Lvl_Det")
Map<String,Object> storedProcCall(@Param("P_LEVEL") String P_LEVEL, @Param("P_POL_SYS_ID") Number P_POL_SYS_ID,
                                  @Param("P_COVER_SYS_ID") Number P_COVER_SYS_ID, @Param("P_SMI_SYS_ID") Number P_SMI_SYS_ID,
                                  @Param("P_LVL_NO") Number P_LVL_NO, @Param("P_LVL_SR_NO") Number P_LVL_SR_NO,
                                  @Param("P_RISK_SYS_ID") Number P_RISK_SYS_ID);

